# JavaScript get set. change set

Tags: javascript, get, set

Why dont firsname set? where is error?

```js
const person = {
    firstName: "Yasar",
    lastName: "KEMAL",

}

Object.defineProperty(person, "fullName", { 
    get function() { //get sadece okuduğu için kısa kod.
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
    },
    set function(value) { //change name set error
        const parts = value.split(' ');
        this.firstName = parts[0];
        this.lastName = parts[1];
    }
})

Object.defineProperty(person, "age", { 
        value: 50,
        writable: true 
    })

person.age = 60;
person.fullName = "Kemalettin TUĞCU" //send name set error

console.log(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the properties added with `Object.defineProperty`, you have to mark those properties as enumerable.

[Read more about `Object.defineProperty()` here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```js
let person = {
    firstName: "Yasar",
    lastName: "KEMAL"
};

Object.defineProperty(person, 'fullName', {
  get() {
    return this.firstName + " "  + this.lastName;
  },
  set(value) {
    [this.firstName, this.lastName] = value.split(" ");
  },
  enumerable:true
});

Object.defineProperty(person, "age", { 
        value: 50,
        writable: true,
        enumerable:true
});

person.age = 60;
person.fullName = "Kemalettin TUĞCU"; //send name set error

console.log(person);
```

Comment: so thanks but;  age change ne problem... now problem have 2 name and last name. " {firstName: "Yasar", lastName: "KEMAL", age: 60, fullName: "Kemalettin TUĞCU"}  "

Comment: @sebahattinküçük See updated answer. The `writable` actually needed to be removed as it is implied when a setter is defined.

Comment: @sebahattinküçük You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote and mark as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top left of the answer.